# TikZ: Plot contour lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have a (continuous) function on the real plane (e. g. `f(x,y)=x^2-x*y`) and want to draw contour lines (e. g. `f(x,y)=-1`, `f(x,y)=1` etc.). Furthermore, I want to adjust the region where to do this (e. g. on the square [-3,3]²). The resulting picture should look like this:

[image: The desired plot]

I know how to do this in MATLAB (using `contour`), but is there any possbility to do this in TikZ? A minimal example doing exactly this would be great!

(A further question: My actual function is the real part of a complex polynomial (e. g. `f(z)=Re(z^2-1)`). Of course, I can manually calculate it using `z=x+iy`, but is there an elegant way to use this complex term directly in TikZ?)

Comment: `tikz`, `pgfplots`  as well any other programs can plot only real function. however, you can calculate parts of complex function, which you like to present by program with given equations.

Comment: @Zarko it could be done with parametric functions in `pgfplots`, or am I wrong on this?

Comment: @Skillmon, to be honest, i don't know. however so far i didn't see diagram of complex function. always was split in two part: `real` and `imaginary` or `amplitude` and `phase`. how you do this is mater of your math skills (off-topic here). maybe is my math knowledge rusty :-)

Answer (score 5):

The pgfplots manual is full of examples for contour plots. **UPDATE**: I missed the fact that the contours are at `+1` *and* `-1`. Big thanks to @Mike for pointing that out!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    title={$x^2-x\,y$},
    enlarge x limits,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
]
\addplot3[domain=-3:3,
        domain y=-3:3,
        contour gnuplot={levels={-1,1},labels=false},
        thick,samples=50,samples y=50,
    ] {x^2-x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you change `levels={1}` to `levels={-1,1}`, you'll get the missing lines.

Comment: @Mike Is it also possible to set `axis y line = middle` and `axis x line = middle`? Because when I did it, the numbers didn't show

Answer (score 3):

Since you have to use `gnuplot` anyway, you could also let it do all the number crunching. It is much faster, but of course, this requires some knowledge about `gnuplot`. In your case, you even have to use the option `raw gnuplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    title={$x^2-x\,y$},
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
]
\addplot gnuplot[raw gnuplot,thick,mark=none]
    {
        unset surface;
        set cntrparam levels discrete -1,1;
        set contour;
        set yrange [-3:3];
        splot [x=-3:3] x**2-x*y;
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]