# Tick labels not showing when using `contour gnuplot` and `axis line = middle`

Tags: gnuplot, ticks

The following code is the modified answer of @user121799 in [TikZ: Plot contour lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434765/tikz-plot-contour-lines). The difference is that I added `axis x line = middle, axis y line = middle` in the first line of the `axis` environment

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    axis x line = middle, axis y line = middle,
    title={$x^2-x\,y$},
    enlarge x limits,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
]
\addplot3[domain=-3:3,
        domain y=-3:3,
        contour gnuplot={levels={-1,1},labels=false},
        thick,samples=50,samples y=50,
    ] {x^2-x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I run then the tick labels are not showing anymore. What is causing it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `axis x line = middle, axis y line = middle,` by `axis lines = middle,`. (I can't explain why your version doesn't work.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    title={$x^2-x\,y$},
    enlarge x limits,
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    small,
]
\addplot3[domain=-3:3,
        domain y=-3:3,
        contour gnuplot={levels={-1,1},labels=false},
        thick,samples=50,samples y=50,
    ] {x^2-x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much!